# TcpTimeoutException when connecting to phone

Tags: python, android, python-asyncio, adb

I'm using the adb_shell python library to run some adb commands through python.

While everything works as intended on the regular version, the async version is failing to connect.

This is the code in the sync version:

```
adbkey = 'adbkey'
with open(adbkey) as f:
    priv = f.read()
with open(adbkey + '.pub') as f:
    pub = f.read()
signer = PythonRSASigner(pub, priv)

# Connect
device1 = AdbDeviceTcp('192.168.0.166', 5555, default_transport_timeout_s=9)
device1.connect(rsa_keys=[signer], auth_timeout_s=0.1)
device.shell("echo Hello")
```

The above works as expected.

However the following version breaks:

```
adbkey = 'adb_key'
with open(adbkey) as f:
    priv = f.read()
with open(adbkey + '.pub') as f:
    pub = f.read()
signer = PythonRSASigner(pub, priv)

# Connect
tcp = TcpTransportAsync('192.168.0.166', port=5555)
device = AdbDeviceAsync(tcp)

await device.connect(rsa_keys=[signer], auth_timeout_s=60)
```

It generates a TcpTimeoutException:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\AdbProject\asyncadb.py", line 77, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\AdbProject\asyncadb.py", line 23, in main
    await device.connect(rsa_keys=[signer], auth_timeout_s=60)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\adb_device_async.py", line 642, in connect
    self._available, self._maxdata = await self._io_manager.connect(self._banner, rsa_keys, auth_timeout_s, auth_callback, adb_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\adb_device_async.py", line 235, in connect
    _, _, maxdata, _ = await self._read_expected_packet_from_device([constants.CNXN], adb_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\adb_device_async.py", line 373, in _read_expected_packet_from_device
    cmd, arg0, arg1, data = await self._read_packet_from_device(adb_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\adb_device_async.py", line 451, in _read_packet_from_device
    msg = await self._read_bytes_from_device(constants.MESSAGE_SIZE, adb_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\adb_device_async.py", line 407, in _read_bytes_from_device
    temp = await self._transport.bulk_read(length, adb_info.transport_timeout_s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\adb_shell\transport\tcp_transport_async.py", line 106, in bulk_read
    raise TcpTimeoutException(msg) from exc
adb_shell.exceptions.TcpTimeoutException: Reading from 192.168.0.166:5555 timed out (60 seconds)
```

Am I meant to do something differently since it's async?

P.S. Both versions work on emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

For some reason the phone was **NOT** showing the prompt to accept adb keys.

Don't know why this would need to be done again if the sync version worked. I was using the same keys.

But eventually it showed the prompt and I accepted it. And it worked.

I guess maybe next time I could manually put the keys on the phone if need be.